# How to modify SSH login prompt so the private key name isn't shown?

Tags: debian, ssh, macos

My work computer is a MacBook, and I have access to a Debian server.
This is my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host jatayu
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User dev001
    Port 22
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentityFile /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxxxx
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

If I type `ssh jatayu` on the terminal, I'll get this response:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/xxxxx/.ssh/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx':
Linux 6.1.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.27-1 (2023-05-08) x86_64
```

Is it possible to change the passphrase prompt into something like: `Enter passphrase:`  (no need to display the private key path)?

Comment: Short answer is: no. Not without rebuilding `ssh` from source. But why do you ask? How does it bother you?

Comment: It's your own private key, right? If you had multiple keys, with different passphrases, how would you know which passphrase to enter (besides memorizing what's in your ~/.ssh/config)?

Comment: @aviro Just a bit of irrational annoyance. Like when I'm demoing my code (with a projector plugged into my laptop), then all the audiences will know the private key path. Yeah I know, what's the actual chance of them copying my SSH keys and knowing the password

Comment: If that's the case, @ctrl-alt-detor's answer about using `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` should work for you when you're doing those demos, as it will not prompt for the passphrase at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ssh-add` to add your key to the ssh agent before trying to login, then you will not be prompted.